# JSON to AVRO to JSON

Tags: scala, apache-spark, avro

I am trying to convert a json file to avro and reverse.

My input file is

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "firstName": "Krish",
    "lastName": "Lee",
    "phoneNumber": "123456",
    "emailAddress": "krish.lee@abc.com"
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "firstName": "racks",
    "lastName": "jacson",
    "phoneNumber": "123456",
    "emailAddress": "racks.jacson@abc.com"
  }
]
```

My output file is

```
{"emailAddress":"krish.lee@abc.com","firstName":"Krish","lastName":"Lee","phoneNumber":"123456","userId":1}
{"emailAddress":"racks.jacson@abc.com","firstName":"racks","lastName":"jacson","phoneNumber":"123456","userId":2}
```

Below is my source code

JSON to Avro

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiLine", true).json("src\\main\\resources\\user.json")
df.printSchema()
df.show()

//convert to avro
df.write.mode("append").format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("src\\main\\resources\\user1")
```

AVRO to JSON

```
val jsonDF = spark.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("src\\main\\resources\\user")

jsonDF.show()
jsonDF.printSchema()
jsonDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).json("src\\main\\resources\\output\\json")
```

Can you please help

Comment: what is your problem ?

Comment: If you look at the input file its a list, with multiple objects. In the output file, I am getting only one object, its not a list.

Comment: while writing you need to convert data into array and write.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code.

**Input Data**

```
scala> import sys.process._

scala> "cat /root/spark-examples/data.json".!
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "firstName": "Krish",
    "lastName": "Lee",
    "phoneNumber": "123456",
    "emailAddress": "krish.lee@abc.com"
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "firstName": "racks",
    "lastName": "jacson",
    "phoneNumber": "123456",
    "emailAddress": "racks.jacson@abc.com"
  }
]
```

Loading json file content into `DataFrame`

```
scala> val df = spark
                  .read
                  .option("multiline","true")
                  .json("/root/spark-examples/data.json")

df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [emailAddress: string, firstName: string ... 3 more fields]
```

Once the json file is loaded into DataFrame, It will be converted into `array of object` into `multiple objects or rows` like below.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+--------------------+---------+--------+-----------+------+
|emailAddress        |firstName|lastName|phoneNumber|userId|
+--------------------+---------+--------+-----------+------+
|krish.lee@abc.com   |Krish    |Lee     |123456     |1     |
|racks.jacson@abc.com|racks    |jacson  |123456     |2     |
+--------------------+---------+--------+-----------+------+
```

When you write `DataFrame` back, It will write it into multiple lines.

```
scala> df.repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").json("/tmp/dataa/")
```

```
scala> "ls -ltr /tmp/dataa/".!
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 222 Oct 22 12:19 part-00000-fa9e79f6-2689-4385-b3ee-fd19cf291a31-c000.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Oct 22 12:19 _SUCCESS
```

```
scala> "cat /tmp/dataa/part-00000-fa9e79f6-2689-4385-b3ee-fd19cf291a31-c000.json".!
{"emailAddress":"krish.lee@abc.com","firstName":"Krish","lastName":"Lee","phoneNumber":"123456","userId":1}
{"emailAddress":"racks.jacson@abc.com","firstName":"racks","lastName":"jacson","phoneNumber":"123456","userId":2}
```

If you want same as your input data, follow below code.

```
scala> df
.select(to_json(collect_list(struct($"*"))).as("data"))
.write
.format("text") // You need to use text format, Using json will give you wrong data.
.mode("overwrite")
.save("/tmp/datab/")
```

```
scala> "ls -ltr /tmp/datab/".!
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 224 Oct 22 12:19 part-00000-0896730e-51e1-4728-bd6b-cdfabc03978e-c000.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Oct 22 12:19 _SUCCESS
```

```
scala> "cat /tmp/datab/part-00000-0896730e-51e1-4728-bd6b-cdfabc03978e-c000.txt".!
[
    {"emailAddress":"krish.lee@abc.com","firstName":"Krish","lastName":"Lee","phoneNumber":"123456","userId":1},
    {"emailAddress":"racks.jacson@abc.com","firstName":"racks","lastName":"jacson","phoneNumber":"123456","userId":2}
]
```